# Everyone in training plays with a very distracting toy

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, training

I'm in training for my new job and the training lasts 2 months. There are 30 employees in the class, and we sit at a computer lab for 8 hours with only one break. It can be very hard to focus as we usually don't get to use the programs we are being trained on and just listen to the instructor speak or watch a video.

Since day one there have been some people in the class who bring [fidget wheels (aka fidget spinners)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidget_spinner).

The instructor is aware people play with these in class and seems alright with it. I certainly find 8 hours of lecture hard to concentrate and don't blaim people for using these. Normally I don't mind but the guy beside me just got a new one and it makes a terrible noise. I cannot focus. The instructor chooses where we sit and I cannot move. I find this guy [very helpful to study with][2] but it's really annoying me how his toy makes noise in class. I don't think the instructor can hear it as he's too far away. Normally things like this don't bug me (for example I can stand pen clicking when most people lose it) but this sound really gets under my skin when I'm trying to learn. I would like to remain on good terms with this person as possible.

What should I do? I see two options:

1. tell the instructor I can't concentrate and ask him to address the whole class about their toys
2. speak to the person beside me directly, but how exactly should I phrase it? I could be direct and just say "the noise that thing makes really irritates me" or less direct "could you put some wd40 on that so it stops making that noise?"

PS For some reason I can't add more than one link, is this intended?

[2]:

Comment: If the teacher gets involved and bans the toy, then everyone who uses it is going to be unhappy, and will probably direct most of that unhappiness at you. Is asking about changing seats a possibility?, if so, that should not only be on the list, but also be higher priority than asking to ban the toy in any way, even indirectly.

Comment: You probably weren't able to add the link due to anti-spam measures. Post the link in comments and someone can edit it in for you.

Answer (score 13):

Communication is key to resolving issues like this.

I'd recommend that you first try to resolve the issue directly with him: maybe after telling him that it makes noise, ask him if he has a quieter one he can play with while he's at work?

Then, if the problem persists, and you can't directly work it out with him, maybe 'escalate' to the person leading training and privately ask him for a different seating arrangement or to ask the class to stop 'fidgeting' with their fidget wheels / fidget spinners.

Answer (score 0):

As annoying as this might be, I think the most professional way to handle this would be to ignore it. If you make an issue of this, the instructor or your coworkers are likely to remember it and judge you for it later.

With 30 people packed in a room for 8 hours, chances are everyone has something they're annoyed about. Just keep in mind that you're probably getting a decent paycheck for dealing with the squeaking, and also that you're getting valuable on-the-job training.

If it was more than two months, you might consider trying to resolve the issue. As it is, the best resolution might be to keep your head down and try to work through it.